# Can both a web server and email server be referenced in the hosts and hostname files?

Tags: linux, web-server, email-server

**Environment:** CentOS, Nginx, Postfix/Dovecot, Digital Ocean Droplet

**Question:** Can both a web server and email server be referenced in the `hosts` and `hostname` files?  Is it better to have a separate email and web server to avoid any possible confusion?

**Background:** I have a web server hosted on a Digital Ocean droplet that I use for testing.  I installed Postfix/Dovecot on this server and everything worked as expected.  However when I checked my setup on [mxtoolbox](https://mxtoolbox.com/) I got a warning.

```
Category: smtp
Host: mail.example.com
Result:  Reverse DNS is not a valid Hostname
```

I checked my `hosts` and `hostname` files and neither referenced the web server.

This is from my `/etc/hosts` file.

```
# The following lines are desirable for IPv4 capable hosts
127.0.0.1 example.com example
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
127.0.0.1 localhost4.localdomain4 localhost4

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 example.com example
::1 localhost.localdomain localhost
::1 localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
```

This is from my `/etc/hostname` file.

```
example.com
```

If I add a reference to the email server in these files will that cause problems?  If I remove the reference to the web server and add the email server will that cause problems?  Would it be better to keep these servers on separate droplets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The contents of your /etc/hosts, and /etc/hostname have nothing to do with the error you are getting from mxtoolbox.  The mxtoolbox error is about DNS.

Pretty sure Digital Ocean sets the reverse DNS to the name of your droplet, in the Digital Ocean control panel. So go into your control panel and give the droplet a valid fqdn as a name.

> Would it be better to keep these servers on separate droplets?

Really shouldn't matter.

Set a name like server1.example.org as the name of your droplet, and then add an `A` record in your zone `example.org` for `server1.example.org` that points at the digital ocean IP addresses for the droplet. You have to have a forward and reverse that match, it have to be the your www.example.org or mail.example.org records that you use in your reverse.